# MySQL trigger on RDS

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs

I am trying to create a MySQL trigger that will invoke a php script. I have a MySQL server instance running in RDS and would like to use the php script to send a message to my SQS messaging system.

1. Where do I save the php scripts?
2. Do I need to install the PHP SDK for SQS on my EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about triggers, especially on Amazon RDS.

Use a cron to execute a PHP script every 5 minutes (for example) that looks for unsent messages and sends them using the SQS messaging system.

Comment: Any reason for suggesting not to use triggers? Is there a known issue with this?

Comment: I think triggers should be avoid whenever possible. Heavily used they make debugging a pain in the ass as they are executed in random order and you often don't think about it when you wonder why the changed data doesn't look as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are the only substitute on MySQL for CHECK constraints, which is a real shame

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use triggers normally. 
Use this steps:

1. Change in "parameter group" menu the variable:

   ```
   log_bin_trust_function_creators to "ON" or "1".
   ```
2. Do a "modify" and "reboot" at instance. MANDATORY!
3. Verify with mysql client if the variable was really modified. The command is: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin_trust%'`

Now, you can create your triggers normally. The great difficult is to check questions correctly: your instance should be use that parameter group, and this should be correctly set